# Running a functions for a specific time

Tags: python

I have a function that listens to my command and converts that to text, I want to create another function that runs the first functions for a given time and if I did not speak for that time, it closes the functions and moves on

Suppose the first function is named takeCommand and the second one as ListenandWait

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print('Recognizing...')
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print('User Said: {}\n'.format(query))
    except:
        print('Say that again please...')
        return 'None'
    return query
```

Comment: At the minimum post a snippet of what you ve tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Show your first function and what you've tried for the second function

Comment: I have tried nothing @Luv because I don't know how to do it

Comment: @Stuart I updated the question to define my first function

Comment: @ArjunBasandrai did you try using ```r.record()``` ?

Comment: @JenilDave I don't know how to use it PLease guide me

Comment: @ArjunBasandrai search on the internet, you will get a lot of examples, you select them according to your application, rather than me giving you reference which might not be suitable to you.